# Reading addIn XML using Xml.Linq

Tags: development, elements-xml

I have seen many instances of this question in this forum, with answers! So why am I still asking?
Because I have tried for hours to read specific parts of the XML below using `XDocument` and yet no succees, here is the whole addIn XML as exported from a page:

```
<webParts>
  <webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3">
    <metaData>
      <type name="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ClientWebPart, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
      <importErrorMessage>Cannot import this Web Part.</importErrorMessage>
    </metaData>
    <data>
      <properties>
        <property name="TitleIconImageUrl" type="string" />
        <property name="Direction" type="direction">NotSet</property>
        <property name="ExportMode" type="exportmode">All</property>
        <property name="HelpUrl" type="string" />
        <property name="Hidden" type="bool">False</property>
        <property name="Description" type="string">Description</property>
        <property name="FeatureId" type="System.Guid, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">624a6c65-81ec-4670-8204-f1e2162e98c0</property>
        <property name="CatalogIconImageUrl" type="string" />
        <property name="Title" type="string">Title</property>
        <property name="AllowHide" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="ProductWebId" type="System.Guid, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">936f3da1-4a4f-46af-b0f8-fbbcb1556430</property>
        <property name="AllowZoneChange" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="TitleUrl" type="string" />
        <property name="ChromeType" type="chrometype">TitleOnly</property>
        <property name="AllowConnect" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="Width" type="unit">350px</property>
        <property name="Height" type="unit" />
        <property name="WebPartName" type="string">WebPart</property>
        <property name="HelpMode" type="helpmode">Navigate</property>
        <property name="AllowEdit" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="AllowMinimize" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="ProductId" type="System.Guid, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">624a6c65-81ec-4670-8204-f1e2162e98bf</property>
        <property name="AllowClose" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="ChromeState" type="chromestate">Normal</property>
      </properties>
    </data>
  </webPart>
</webParts>
```

I can load the XML using:

```
XDocument addinTemplate = XDocument.Load("AddInTemplate.xml");
```

with no problems, but when I try to reach any other part of the XML like the , it just doesn't work.
Shouldn't it be as simple as
`var properties = addinTemplate.Descendants("properties");` ?
What am I missing?
I have also tried to create my own simple XML structure and had no problems getting any specific element/attribute from it, what is different with addIn XML?
My goal is to reach the properties element to loop through its property children.

**Update**

**Using:**

```
var properties = addinTemplate.Descendants("properties").Select(p => new
            {
                name = p.Attribute("name"),
                type = p.Attribute("type")
            }).ToList();
```

**Or:**

```
var properties = addinTemplate.Descendants("properties");
```

does not yield any results, without getting an error message.

Comment: does your XML file contains `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>` in the top?

Comment: Yes it does, but it does not seem to help, when I tried with another simple XML structure, it worked without having <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

Comment: Any error your are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var properties = addinTemplate.Descendants("properties")
                       .Select(p => new { 
                                         name = p.Attribute("name"), 
                                         type = p.Attribute("type")}
                       ).ToList();
```

Instead of above, try following and let me know.

```
var properties = addinTemplate
                     .Descendants()
                     .Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "properties")
                     .ToList();
```

**Update #1**

Following will give all `Descendants` under `properties`

```
var properties = addinTemplate.Descendants()
            .Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "properties")
            .Descendants()
            .Select(p => new { name = p.Attribute("name"), type = p.Attribute("type") })
            .ToList();
```

I have tested it.

Comment: Works perfectly! I began to remove parts of the XML to see what it is that stopped it from working, it was really the <webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3"></webPart> element, when i removed this element, everything works fine, and it's only this element that has xmlns definition, anything to consider about that?

Comment: Sure, I'm not running away :)

Comment: If you are not run away already, then find my another update. :)